# Number Formatting and storing

Tags: numpy

I have Big numpy array with numbers like `1.01594734e+09` 
I just want this data as integers or rounded off till 5 decimals in case of  `1.01594734e+03`
or something like that

Comment: Why Downvoting ? I am really stuck in this problem.. and I tried using Numpy.around . And it matters when you dont get expected results with these numbers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose what you want. I assume you want to make the array smaller.

If you want to convert array `a` into integers, then:

```
a_int = a.astype('int')
```

However, keep in mind that this does not save any storage space as `int` is an 8-octet (64-bit) integer, and `float` is an 8-octet float.

If you know you have integer data which is limited in size, you may specify the storage format to be something shorter:

```
a_int = a.astype('int32')
```

If you have pure integer data which fits into the destination type, there is no loss of precision in this conversion.

On the other hand - depending on your data - you may have equally good results by using 4-octet (32-bit) floats:

```
a_shortfloat = a.astype('float32')
```

This conversion causes some loss of precision depending on the data.

The second alternative you suggest is to round a number into a given number of decimals, there are two quite different possibilities.

Simple rounding to 5 decimals:

```
a_rounded = a.round(decimals=5)
```

This, however, does not save any storage space, the numbers are only rounded (and they are not accurate even after that due to the limitations of the floating point representation).

Another possibility is to use a fixed point notation:

```
a_fixedpoint = (a * 100000 + .5).astype('int32')
```

With this representation your example number `1.01594734e+03` will become 101 594 734. Whether or not this is a useful representation depends on the application. Sometimes fixed-point numbers are very useful, but if your numbers have a wide dynamic range (e.g. from 1e-5 to 1e5), then floating point numbers are the correct way of handling them.